# Exceptions in Visual Studio 2010 AddIn

Tags: vb.net, exception, visual-studio-addins

I have a WinForms application raising exceptions from code in an EventHandler (E.G. a Button click subscriber);

I have a try..catch block around the invocation of the ShowDialog of the Form;

The exception does not propagate to the try..catch block, but it just stops at the handler and the Form gets closed.

1) How can I propagate the exception to the block?

2) What is the best practice in these cases?

This is a new VS 2010 AddIn probject with a simple Tools menu entry added by the wizard:

```
    Public Sub Exec(ByVal commandName As String, ByVal executeOption As vsCommandExecOption, ByRef varIn As Object, ByRef varOut As Object, ByRef handled As Boolean) Implements IDTCommandTarget.Exec
        handled = False
        If executeOption = vsCommandExecOption.vsCommandExecOptionDoDefault Then
            If commandName = "MyAddin1.Connect.MyAddin1" Then

                Dim form1 = New Form1

                Try
                    form1.ShowDialog()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                End Try

                handled = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

The only content of the Form is a button with a static handler raising a "New Exception()".

When I click the button, the exception is not caught.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Forms each event handler needs its own try/catch block, or you can try to use [Application.ThreadException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) although maybe it is not possible in an add-in. See [Top-Level Exception Handling In Windows Forms Applications](https://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/08/top-level-exception-handling-in-windows-forms-applications-part-1/)

Comment: I wanted to avoid a try...catch in every event handler, it seems a big violation of DRY... (and additional mechanical work/error prone)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a global exception handler and it's not working from the addin for me, too.